# Ajax request doesn't work for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, ajax-request

I am so new for ajax and jquery!

At the below, my codes are working as a charm at desktop pc's.

I can collect the spent  time for clients, but in mobile devices ajax request is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var startTime = new Date();        //Start the clock!
window.onbeforeunload = function()        //When the user leaves the page(closes the window/tab, clicks a link)...
{
    var endTime = new Date();        //Get the current time.
    var timeSpent = (endTime - startTime);        //Find out how long it's been.
    var xmlhttp;        //Make a variable for a new ajax request.
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)        //If it's a decent browser...
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        //Open a new ajax request.
    }
    else        //If it's a bad browser...
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");        //Open a different type of ajax call.
    }
    var url = "http://www.example.com/time.php?time="+timeSpent;        //Send the time on the page to a php script of your choosing.
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);        //The false at the end tells ajax to use a synchronous call which wont be severed by the user leaving.
    xmlhttp.send(null);        //Send the request and don't wait for a response.
}
</script>
```

It doesnt work for my phone (iphone)!

Anyone could help me out please?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm what mobile device(s) you're testing on?

Comment: Only Iphone 6, apple device, i tested

Comment: You answered it in the question (iPhone).

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var startTime = new Date();        //Start the clock!
var isOnIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
var eventName = isOnIOS ? "pagehide" : "beforeunload";

window.addEventListener(eventName, function (event) { 
    var endTime = new Date();        //Get the current time.
    var timeSpent = (endTime - startTime);        //Find out how long it's been.
    var xmlhttp;        //Make a variable for a new ajax request.
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)        //If it's a decent browser...
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        //Open a new ajax request.
    }
    else        //If it's a bad browser...
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");        //Open a different type of ajax call.
    }
    var url = "http://www.example.com/time.php?time="+timeSpent;        //Send the time on the page to a php script of your choosing.
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);        //The false at the end tells ajax to use a synchronous call which wont be severed by the user leaving.
    xmlhttp.send(null);        //Send the request and don't wait for a response.
});
</script>
```

This event will work for both browsers and iOS devices as well.

Comment: @Bagova Does this solution works for you? Let me know so that it helps others too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem was caused by the fact that mobile device don't support `window.onbeforeunload`. To have similar effect, try `document.unload` or `document.pagehide`